# Filling the table row space completely with image, text and EditText

Tags: android

I have a fixed size image button, text and an EditText that I want to fill the whole table row. Image button size is 100x100 which means I want text and the edit text to occupy the rest of the space in the row.

I came up with the following code. But complete row space is not used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Experts, please help.

Comment: 100 pixels in not not suit for every device screen, can you mention it as percentage such as 30 %, 40% etc

Answer (score 0):

See below version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Kevin, getting error for  android:layout_width="0dp" in the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting android:layout_weight="1" for the outer most Horizontal LinearLayout. I Got the behavior I expected.